# Rename "Add Media" Button To "Add Images"

Tags: media

I would like to rename the "Add Media" button (just above the post editor interface) to be "Add Images". I can't seem to find the appropriate filter for this. There seems to be a filter that has now been deprecated but I can't figure out what the new method is. The legacy filter was `media_buttons_context`.

Comment: I'm curious, why? You're aware it's possible to add video, sound, PDFs, etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The button text being a translatable string, you can make use of the [gettext filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext):

```
function wpse95025_rename_media_button( $translation, $text ) {
    if( is_admin() && 'Add Media' === $text ) {
        return 'Add Images';
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', wpse95025_rename_media_button, 10, 2 );
```

For the sake of completeness:
Of course, you can also keep the new string translatable.

```
function wpse95025_rename_media_button( $translation, $text ) {
    if( is_admin() && 'Add Media' === $text ) {
        return __( 'Add Images', 'your-text-domain' );
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', wpse95025_rename_media_button, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I wasn't familiar with that filter. Appreciate the response.

Comment: If this solved you're issue, @Peter (which I am confident it did), be so kind as to tick the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark your question as answered, such that others can tell that it is in the future.

Comment: +1. I had to rename that buttons for all the authors, so tweaked your code a bit and it worked like charm. Thanks.

Comment: While you might have discovered this in the process of having to rename the same button, @Sanu_012, the filter is applicable to any translatable string within the WP codebase. FYI.